# Flex container width equal to width of all flex items in the first row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Is there a way to make a flex container width be set to width of all flex items in the first row?

Here is the code to recreate my mock page:

```js
let tags = ["whatever", 'whenever', 'follower', 'leaves', 'trees', 'follow', 'sea', 'ocean'];

const addTagsToHTML = function(tags) {
  let tagsList = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-list')[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    let spanEl = document.createElement('span')
    spanEl.className = 'tag';
    spanEl.innerHTML = tags[i];
    tagsList.appendChild(spanEl);
  }
}

addTagsToHTML(tags)

const deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete-btn');
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("to delete");
  let spanEl = document.getElementsByClassName('tag')[0];
  let tagsList = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-list')[0];
  tagsList.removeChild(spanEl);
})
```

```css
.all-container {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: rgb(231, 248, 228);
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.add-padd-color {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.tag-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tag-list .tag {
  border: 1px solid rgb(182, 112, 112);
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  ;
}

.actions,
.title {
  min-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-container">
  <div class="title add-padd-color">Mock title</div>
  <div class="tag-list add-padd-color">
  </div>
  <div class="actions add-padd-color">
    <button id='delete-btn'>Delete tag</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is how this page looks like:
[image][image]

These flex items (tags) may be deleted, so the width of first row will change and I want my flex container's (tag-list) width to change accordingly and to take up only the size that is needed to contain all flex items that can be contained in a row without leaving free space.

Comment: Use `flex-grow` and `flex-shrink` properties to grow or shrink flex items respectively.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Flex container</title>
    <style>
        .all-container {
            width: 90%;
            background-color: rgb(231, 248, 228);
            display: flex;
            padding: 10px;
            gap: 10px;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }

        .add-padd-color {
            padding: 20px;
            background-color: white;
        }

        .tag-list {
            display: flex;
            gap: 10px;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            flex-grow: 1;
        }

        .tag-list .tag {
            border: 1px solid rgb(182, 112, 112);
            padding: 2px 5px;
            border-radius: 2px;
            ;
        }

        .actions,
        .title {
            min-width: 30%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="all-container">
        <div class="title add-padd-color">Mock title</div>
        <div class="tag-list add-padd-color">
        </div>
        <div class="actions add-padd-color">
            <button id='delete-btn'>Delete tag</button>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        let tags = ["whatever", 'whenever', 'follower', 'leaves', 'trees', 'follow', 'sea', 'ocean'];

        const addTagsToHTML = function (tags) {
            let tagsList = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-list')[0];
            for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
                let spanEl = document.createElement('span')
                spanEl.className = 'tag';
                spanEl.innerHTML = tags[i];
                tagsList.appendChild(spanEl);
            }
        }

        addTagsToHTML(tags)

        const deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete-btn');
        deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
            console.log("to delete");
            let spanEl = document.getElementsByClassName('tag')[0];
            let tagsList = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-list')[0];
            tagsList.removeChild(spanEl);
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can use `flex-grow` on the .tag-list so that the tag-list container takes up the space that is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a parent div to your `.all-container` div.
And add `display: flex` to the parent div.
You can see the code for it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ucLmdbf5/4/

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that you want the container width to adjust to the shrinking middle item, then instead of `display: flex` use `display: inline-flex`.

```js
let tags = ["whatever", 'whenever', 'follower', 'leaves', 'trees', 'follow', 'sea', 'ocean'];

const addTagsToHTML = function(tags) {
  let tagsList = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-list')[0];
  for (let i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    let spanEl = document.createElement('span')
    spanEl.className = 'tag';
    spanEl.innerHTML = tags[i];
    tagsList.appendChild(spanEl);
  }
}

addTagsToHTML(tags)

const deleteBtn = document.getElementById('delete-btn');
deleteBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log("to delete");
  let spanEl = document.getElementsByClassName('tag')[0];
  let tagsList = document.getElementsByClassName('tag-list')[0];
  tagsList.removeChild(spanEl);
})
```

```css
.all-container {
  /* width: 90%; */
  /* background-color: rgb(231, 248, 228); */
  /* hard to see */
  background-color: gray;
  /* for demo purposes */
  display: inline-flex;
  /* adjustment */
  padding: 10px;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.add-padd-color {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

.tag-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.tag-list .tag {
  border: 1px solid rgb(182, 112, 112);
  padding: 2px 5px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  ;
}

.actions,
.title {
  min-width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="all-container">
  <div class="title add-padd-color">Mock title</div>
  <div class="tag-list add-padd-color">
  </div>
  <div class="actions add-padd-color">
    <button id='delete-btn'>Delete tag</button>
  </div>
</div>
```